# Dynamic query based on column value in select statement of Ibatis?

Tags: dynamic, ibatis

I need to have inheritance mapping in ibatis. In Ibatis documentation, what I have learned is, we can compare the value of the column to call submaps inside discriminator tag of resultMap like as follows:

```
<resultMap id="map">
<discriminator javaType="java.lang.Integer" column="type">
<subMap resultMap="submap1" value="1" />
<subMap resultMap="submap2" value="2"/>
<subMap resultMap="submap3" value="3"/>
</discriminator>
</resultMap>
```

In the above resultmap, the submaps maps the columns to different object.

But I want to compare the value of column in select statement itself so that I can get the required columns. some what like as follows:

```
<select id="load" resultMap="map">
select mt.id,mt.name, mt.type
<here we have to check the value of type column returned dynamically>
<if type = "1">
table1.column1, table1.column2 ... table1.columnN 
</if>
<if type = "2">
table2.column1, table2.column2 ... table2.columnN 
</if>
</here>
from main_table mt
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE1 table1 ON mt.id=table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 table2 ON mt.id=table2
where mt.id=#value#
</select>
```

This is just an algorithm for my requirement. Is it possible in Ibatis?

Hope you understand my problem. If the question is not clear, I am happy to reedit this to make you clear.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could try in following way?

```
<select id="load" resultMap="map">
     select mt.id,mt.name, mt.type
     <if type = "1">
         table1.column1, table1.column2 ... table1.columnN 
     </if>
     <if type = "2">
         table2.column1, table2.column2 ... table2.columnN 
     </if>
     from main_table mt
     <if type = "1">
         LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE1 table1 ON mt.id=table1
     </if>
     <if type = "2">
         LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 table2 ON mt.id=table2
     </if>
     where mt.id=#{value}
</select>
```

If you face some error in above way please reply...